# Where is the Tomcat7 WEB root in Ubuntu 14

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ubuntu

I have just installed Tomcat 7 for my JSP projects via apt-get so it is installed as a service. I am using Ubuntu 14.10 LTS

I run this code to install everything about Tomcat 7.0.61

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-docs tomcat7-examples tomcat7-common tomcat7-admin tomcat7-user
```

Then I found that there is tomcat7, tomcat7-docs, tomcat7-examples, and tomcat7-admin installed in /usr/share folder

This makes me completely confused cuz I can run examples and docs via the url http://localhost:8080/examples or http://localhost:8080/docs

Note that the examples and docs folders are in /usr/share. So I feel like the /usr/share folder is my web root for Tomcat 7 because those folders are in there.

However, in /var/lib/tomcat7/, there is webapps folder but when I try putting file in the folder, the file is not working at all.

So anyone can explain where the webapps or root folder for Tomcat is? and how to properly set the path for the web root folder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tomcat webapps root is `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/` and you may want to set a soft link to it in `/usr/share/tomcat7` :

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7/
ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ .
```

and same for `conf`

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/ .
```

and for `log`:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
ln -s /var/log/tomcat7 .
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. basically, after I app-get installed tomcat, it started up looking for all of these working directories in /usr/share/tomcat7. when it didn't find them, it failed silently. to see the fails you need to look at the log via tail -f logs/catalina.out

Answer (score 4):

Well you can generally find the tomcat installation at,

```
/usr/share/tomcat7
```

Or the other thing you can do is download the [tar.gz] package of Tomcat. Then unpack it with the following command

```
tar xvzf apache-tomcat-7.0.61.tar.gz
```

After you do that move the same to the required directory /usr/share/tomcat7 by

```
sudo mv apache-tomcat-7.0.61/ /usr/share/tomcat7
```

Sometimes tomcat is not recognized , but a surefire way of recognizing that tomcat is to define the file paths inside "catalina.sh" located in tomcat7/bin. To modify this file use the command:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh
```

Thus you will have a fresh installation of Tomcat 7 as per your needs but don't forget to remove previous Tomcat install before following the above!

Answer (score 3):

You have three main directories for Tomcat:

- `/etc/tomcat7` for configuration
- `/etc/tomcat7` for runtime, called CATALINA_HOME
- `/usr/share/tomcat7-root` for webapps

The alternative path to Tomcat, called CATALINA_BASE, is `/var/lib/tomcat7`